# How to get the values from multiple groups of Quasar toggle buttons in Vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

We use Quasar framework in our Vue.js app. There is a modal dialog where I have multiple groups of toggle buttons (q-btn-toggle). The screenshot looks as following:

[image]

As you can see there are women (masters) who provide cosmetical services to clients. There are also 2 amounts below. The first one "Summary" is total amount that client should pay. The second one "Tip" should be calculated from toggle buttons groups next to each master. There are 2 types of tip: percentages of total amount and fixed amounts. As you can see in my code I only can get the value of one (for all) toggle buttons groups. It means when I select some button for any master, the same button will be selected for other masters as well. But, I need to have the possiblity to separately select different buttons for particular master.

The code looks as following:

```
<template>
  <q-dialog v-model="show" no-backdrop-dismiss full-width>
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section class="row items-center">
        <div class="text-h6">Tip</div>
        <q-space />
        <q-btn icon="close" flat round dense v-close-popup @click="cancel" />
      </q-card-section>
      <q-card-section style="max-height: 50vh" class="scroll set-border">
        <div class="q-gutter-md">
          <q-card v-for="{ master } in items" :key="master.id">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-2 flex justify-center items-center">
                <Avatar
                  :src="master.employer_avatar"
                  :size="50"
                  no-default-spinner
                />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <q-card-section>
                  <q-btn-toggle
                    v-model="togglePercentPayment"
                    toggle-color="primary"
                    :options="percentPayments"
                    spread
                    @input="getFullTip"
                  />
                </q-card-section>
                <q-card-section>
                  <q-btn-toggle
                    v-model="toggleStandardPayment"
                    toggle-color="primary"
                    :options="standardPayments"
                    spread
                    @input="getFullTip"
                  />
                </q-card-section>
              </div>
            </div>
          </q-card>
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
      <q-card-section>
        <div><strong>Summary:</strong> {{ total }} руб.</div>
        <div>
          <strong>Tip:</strong> {{ getFullTip() ? getFullTip() : 0 }} руб.
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
      <q-card-actions align="right" class="text-primary q-pt-none">
        <q-btn flat label="Pay" @click="pay" />
        <q-btn flat label="Cancel" @click="cancel" />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
</template>

<script>
const percentPayments = [
  { label: '5%', value: 5 },
  { label: '10%', value: 10 },
  { label: '15%', value: 15 },
]

const standardPayments = [
  { label: '100', value: 100 },
  { label: '200', value: 200 },
  { label: '500', value: 500 },
]

export default {
  props: {
    showModal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    total: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      show: false,
      togglePercentPayment: null,
      toggleStandardPayment: null,
      percentPayments,
      standardPayments,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    showModal(newVal) {
      this.show = newVal
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPercentage(total, percent) {
      return (total / 100) * percent
    },
    getFullTip() {
      const percentToggleSum = this.getPercentage(
        this.total,
        this.togglePercentPayment,
      )
      return percentToggleSum + this.toggleStandardPayment
    },
    pay() {
      this.$emit('pay', this.getFullTip())
      this.clear()
    },
    cancel() {
      this.$emit('cancel')
      this.clear()
    },
    clear() {
      this.togglePercentPayment = null
      this.toggleStandardPayment = null
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.set-border {
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
}
</style>
```

My question is how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `togglePercentPayment` and `toggleStandardPayment` should be array. Because you consider only two variable for all masters and it's natural that all of them are dependent to each other.

You can define them as array. something like this for `data` property:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      show: false,
      togglePercentPayment: [null, null],
      toggleStandardPayment: [null, null],
      percentPayments,
      standardPayments,
    }
},
```

And in template section:

```
<q-card v-for="({ master }, index) in items" :key="master.id">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 flex justify-center items-center">
                <Avatar
                  :src="master.employer_avatar"
                  :size="50"
                  no-default-spinner
                />
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <q-card-section>
                  <q-btn-toggle
                    v-model="togglePercentPayment[index]"
                    toggle-color="primary"
                    :options="percentPayments"
                    spread
                    @input="getFullTip"
                  />
                </q-card-section>
                <q-card-section>
                  <q-btn-toggle
                    v-model="toggleStandardPayment[index]"
                    toggle-color="primary"
                    :options="standardPayments"
                    spread
                    @input="getFullTip"
                  />
            </q-card-section>
        </div>
   </div>
</q-card>
```

In addition, if number of masters is not necessarily equal 2, you can construct the array based on the length of `masters`. Something like this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      show: false,
      togglePercentPayment: new Array(this.items.length).fill(null),
      toggleStandardPayment: new Array(this.items.length).fill(null),
      percentPayments,
      standardPayments,
    }
},
```

Comment: Yes, there can be more than 2 masters. I'm not sure how to construct arrays based on length of masters.

Comment: You can write `togglePercentPayment: new Array(this.items.length).fill(null)`